# Making dynamic memory executable and spawning a thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it possible to load dynamic memory with executable instructions and spawn a thread to run it?

I understand you can turn dynamic memory into an executable section but this is a little more complicated.

Comment: Seems like this question is equivalent to asking if self-modifying code is supported in Linux.  If so, the answer to the questions is (AFAIK) yes, but it's not recommended unless you really, really know what you are doing and why.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `libdl` and `dlopen`, `dlsym`, and `dlclose`.

---

You create a `.so` from:

```
// tsk.c -- shared library

#include <stdio.h>

// entry -- thread function
void *
entry(void *ptr)
{

    printf("entry: i am my%d\n",MYNAME);

    return (void *) 0;
}
```

---

Create a program to load the dynamic objects (e.g.):

```
// loader.c -- load shared objects dynamically

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int
main(void)
{

    for (int ilib = 0;  ilib < 3;  ++ilib) {
        char file[100];
        sprintf(file,"./my%d.so",ilib);

        // load shared relocatable into memory
        void *lib = dlopen(file,RTLD_LAZY);
        if (lib == NULL) {
            printf("dlopen fail -- %s\n",dlerror());
            exit(1);
        }

        // find the address of the thread function
        void *sym = dlsym(lib,"entry");

        pthread_t tid;

        // create the thread with call to object's thread function
        pthread_create(&tid,NULL,sym,NULL);

        // wait for thread completion
        pthread_join(tid,NULL);

        // unload the shared object
        dlclose(lib);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Create the programs:

```
cc -o my0.so -shared -fPIC -DMYNAME=0 tsk.c
cc -o my1.so -shared -fPIC -DMYNAME=1 tsk.c
cc -o my2.so -shared -fPIC -DMYNAME=2 tsk.c
cc -g -o loader loader.c -lpthread -ldl
```

---

Now, just run the loader program with `./loader`:

```
entry: i am my0
entry: i am my1
entry: i am my2
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "dynamic memory." You can allocate [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) of memory in Linux and make them executable by calling [`mmap(...)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) But if you want to grant execute permission to memory blobs that you got from `malloc()`, then I'm *guessing* that it's not possible. (Speaking for myself, Even if it *was* possible, I would never advise anybody to do it.)

---

If your program is going to read in data from any external source, then I hope you appreciate the security implications of having memory pages that are both writable and executable.

Comment: Does page allocation with mmap work like malloc? IIRC mmap was traditionally used to access hardware registers directly, I didn't know it could allocate memory.

Comment: @FourierFlux [On linux, at least] `malloc` will use `brk/sbrk` for small allocations. But, for large ones, it will call `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` instead. It will remember this and if you call `free` for such a block, it may put it back into its free pool or it may release the memory back to the system with `munmap` As for `mmap` access to H/W registers, this [usually] isn't a good idea because you could be interrupted [to the kernel] and you can't control atomic access to the registers (e.g. You're setting up DMA regs for video transfer and need all to be set at once).

Comment: @FourierFlux, The purpose of `mmap()` is to give a program control over what it means to access some span of virtual memory pages. It could mean, access to pages of some file (which could be a device special file), access to pages shared with another process, etc. One possibility is to access ordinary read/write VM pages. In any case, you can either specify the virtual address where you want the pages to appear, or you can let `mmap()` choose it for you. If you let `mmap()` choose the address of ordinary read/write pages, then yeah, I guess that's kind of like a coarse grained `malloc()`.